# Adjust drawable size according to screen size

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, imageview, drawable

I am displaying some TexViews on the screen. They contains text as well as a drawable image also . My question is the how can  I scale the drawable according to the screen resolution 
below is my code currently running :

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 35, 35, true));
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null,null,null);
```

Here I used ratio 35 but when we run the application on bigger screen the images appear to be small .

Any suggestion to scale image for different screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the density scale:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
mainContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
float densityScale = dm.density;
```

Then scale the required size by the densityScale value before using:

```
float scaledWidth = 35 * densityScale;
float scaledHeight = 35 * densityScale;

Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true));
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null,null,null);
```

This assumes that 35 is the correct size for 160dpi. If not you will need to change the 35 to a value appropriate for 160dpi.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info about supporting multiple resolutions/densities.